# Issues with Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I am having issues with creating this recursive method. The method needs to add objects to a stack.

Notes:
This is a path finder project.

`getNextBird()` polls from a bird queue inside the bird object. If the queue is empty it will return null; if it is not empty it will return the next bird inside the queue.

I cannot use any loops at all. (It would have been easy if I could.)
The last element in the stack has to be Bird "end". But if the code works fine it should be done recursively.

My issue is that there is a edge-case where the checks hit a wall where `getNextBird` becomes null (in this instance the object bird), and I want to pop the newest object from the stack. I will get a StackOverflow error, or a EmptyCollection error.

```
private static boolean recurse(Stack<Bird> path, Bird current, Bird end) 
{
    Bird bird = null;
    if (current != null) {
        bird = current.getNextBird();
        if (bird != null) {
            path.push(current);
            recurse(path, bird, end);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

import java.util.Stack;

```
public class Solve2
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    // create the maze to solve
    Maze maze = new Maze();

    // create a Stack of Bird objects named path here
    Stack<Bird> path = new Stack<Bird>();

    // call recursive method to solve the maze and print the path
    recurse(path, maze.getStart(), maze.getEnd());
    print(path);
  }


  private static boolean recurse(Stack<Bird> path, Bird current, Bird end) 
  {
      Bird bird = null;
      if (current != null) {
          bird = current.getNextBird();
          if (bird != null) {
              path.push(current);
              recurse(path, bird, end);
              return true;
          } else {
              path.pop();
              recurse(path, path.peek(), end);
              return false;
          }
      }
      return false;  
  }


  private static void print(Stack<Bird> stack)
  {
    // write your code for recursively printing the stack here
 System.out.println(stack.pop());
 print(stack);

  }

}
```

The Bird class:

```
public class Bird
{
  public static final int N  = 0;
  public static final int NE = 1;
  public static final int E  = 2;
  public static final int SE = 3;
  public static final int S  = 4;
  public static final int SW = 5;
  public static final int W  = 6;
  public static final int NW = 7;

  private static final String [] directions = {"N ", "NE", "E ", "SE", "S ", "SW", "W ", "NW"};

  private String name;
  private int direction;
  private Queue<Bird> queue;

  public Bird(int row, int column, int direction)
  {
    this.name = "Row/Column [" + row + "][" + column + "]";
    this.direction = direction;
  }

  public void setBirdQueue(Queue<Bird> queue)
  {
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return "Location: " + name + ", Direction: " + directions[direction];
  }

  public int getDirection()
  {
    return this.direction;
  }
  public Bird getNextBird()
  {
    // write code to return the next Bird from the queue or null if no Birds left.
      return queue.poll();
  }
}
```

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

```
public class Maze
{
  private Bird start;
  private Bird end;

  public Maze()
  {
    // construct the diagrammed maze
    int MAX_ROW = 5;
    int MAX_COL = 7;
    Bird [][] maze = new Bird[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];

    // row 0
    maze[0][0] = new Bird(0, 0, Bird.S);
    maze[0][1] = new Bird(0, 1, Bird.SW);
    maze[0][2] = new Bird(0, 2, Bird.S);
    maze[0][3] = new Bird(0, 3, Bird.SE);
    maze[0][4] = new Bird(0, 4, Bird.SW);
    maze[0][5] = new Bird(0, 5, Bird.SW);
    maze[0][6] = new Bird(0, 6, Bird.SW);

    // row 1
    maze[1][0] = new Bird(1, 0, Bird.S);
    maze[1][1] = new Bird(1, 1, Bird.W);
    maze[1][2] = new Bird(1, 2, Bird.SW);
    maze[1][3] = new Bird(1, 3, Bird.S);
    maze[1][4] = new Bird(1, 4, Bird.N);
    maze[1][5] = new Bird(1, 5, Bird.S);
    maze[1][6] = new Bird(1, 6, Bird.W);

    // row 2
    maze[2][0] = new Bird(2, 0, Bird.NE);
    maze[2][1] = new Bird(2, 1, Bird.NW);
    maze[2][2] = new Bird(2, 2, Bird.N);
    maze[2][3] = new Bird(2, 3, Bird.W);
    maze[2][4] = new Bird(2, 4, Bird.SE);
    maze[2][5] = new Bird(2, 5, Bird.NE);
    maze[2][6] = new Bird(2, 6, Bird.E);

    // row 3
    maze[3][0] = new Bird(3, 0, Bird.SE);
    maze[3][1] = new Bird(3, 1, Bird.NE);
    maze[3][2] = new Bird(3, 2, Bird.E);
    maze[3][3] = new Bird(3, 3, Bird.NW);
    maze[3][4] = new Bird(3, 4, Bird.NW);
    maze[3][5] = new Bird(3, 5, Bird.E);
    maze[3][6] = new Bird(3, 6, Bird.W);

    // row 4
    maze[4][0] = new Bird(4, 0, Bird.N);
    maze[4][1] = new Bird(4, 1, Bird.NE);
    maze[4][2] = new Bird(4, 2, Bird.N);
    maze[4][3] = new Bird(4, 3, Bird.N);
    maze[4][4] = new Bird(4, 4, Bird.NE);
    maze[4][5] = new Bird(4, 5, Bird.W);
    maze[4][6] = new Bird(4, 6, Bird.N);

    start = maze[2][0];
    end   = maze[2][6];

    // write your code here
    /*snipped the logic for adding the birds in the queue, but I do know that this part is 100% functional on my end*/
  }

  public Bird getStart()
  {
    return this.start;
  }

  public Bird getEnd()
  {
    return this.end;
  }

}
```

Comment: What is Bird data structure? and what is your input data. Maybe you've created some sort of loop and go to same bird again and again?.... It would be useful for you to add System.out.println(bird) in the middle.

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace and an example of the edge-case?

Comment: @mst It does not loop the same bird over and over.

Comment: Recursion is just another name for the issue. Use iteration instead.

Comment: I updated the post. @jackwilsdon

Comment: My professor wants me to do this using recursion @TheLaw

Comment: @TheLaw Well half of the project was to use a method of iteration, which was easy. But this part makes me want to pull my hair out.

Comment: How do you call this method. Show us input data. What is bird and what is in `stack` at the start?

Comment: @mst It is being called in the main method of the project. The stack is empty, and we are filling it in this method.

Comment: what is the `getNextBird` returns for `current` on first step?

Comment: It will return the final bird (I know that part works, because part of the project required us to use loops to find our way through the maze).

Comment: Change  recurse(path, path.peek(), end); to              recurse(path, bird, end);

Comment: @R Quijano, Hmm interesting, once I did that it lead me to another wall, but it did start going to the right path. I guess there is one other case to consider, I will check it out.

Comment: give me the data structure of the bird, i will give the answer!

Comment: @Nguyen Doan Tung updated if you want to take a go at it.

Comment: Does it mean a bird can have only one next bird based on one direction?

Comment: All the birds in the direction the current bird is facing will be added to that birds queue.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, one thing I am seeing that you have passed the parameter `end` in the recursion but never used that.

One key thing of recursion is having a **control statement** which will cause the recursion to break and return the right thing or nothing. You have returned true and false randomly (or may be there is a logic) which does not add any value to your execution path.

So, let's do it in a different way:

1. Don't push anything in the stack unless you need it so that you have to only pop when you are printing. The first bird you need to push in the stack is the **final bird** matching the expression `(current == end)`.
2. If the bird does not have return something to the previous bird indicating that the path is blocked. Now to match with this, with Step 1, if `(current == end)` return something to the previous bird indicating that the final bird is found and pass it on with every bird in the chain to the first bird.

**Pseudocode:**

```
recursive(stack, current, end)
{
    if(current == end){
        stack.push(current); //push the final bird
        return true; //indication that final is found
    }
    else if(current.getNext() != null){
        result = recurse(stack, current.getNext(), end); //recurse
        if(result == true)
          stack.push(current); // using indication from the chain

        return result; 
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is true, you are correct! But my issue is how I am going about pushing, and popping the stack. Because the stack should not become empty in that method, it should only remove the un-needed bird objects.

Comment: What makes the bird un-needed?

Comment: So if the next bird in the bird queue (which is inside each bird object, and it is called using getNextBird), becomes null without it reaching the final bird then that specific bird object is removed from the stack. Also what is the keyboard shortcut for that wrapper you are using around the code?